# An exception compiling PlayORM example

Tags: playorm

I get an exception compiling "Example.java" after I created "User.java" and blank "Persistence.java". Here are the details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/astyanax/AstyanaxConfiguration
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.createInstance(Bootstrap.java:71)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:64)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:60)
at nosql.Example.main(Example.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.astyanax.AstyanaxConfiguration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

From what I undestood no Cassandra installation is required for the in-memory database test.

What do I need to do?

Comment: It is an open issue.. https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/issues/10  so you need all the jars as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out adding "playorm-master.jar" to the Build Path is not enough.
The problem was solved by adding all the "output/jardist" jars to the Build Path.

Comment: yes, you need all the jars that playorm depends on as well ;).